# on click of enter key textview should lose the focus

Tags: android

I have the `TextView` variable **regvalue** which takes the input 5 digit number from user and on pressing enter button from keyboard the `TextView` should loose its focus and perform the action specified within it.

The code snippet that I have written is as follows:

```
regValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
             new Writereg1().execute();
            //do job here when EditText loses focus
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it by setting a `OnKeyListener` on your `View`

```
yourView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    // clear focus from current view
                    // request focus on another view
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  editText
                    .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                                KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                            if (id == R.id.edittext|| id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                                 new Writereg1().execute();
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```